# How to use react-select with redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to integrate react-select using redux form...

**Here is my code**

```
import Select from 'react-select'
import StyledSelectField, { StyledMessages } from './style'

const SelectField = props => {
  const { input, label, placeholder, options, meta, ...StyledProps } = props
  const { onChange, onBlur, onFocus } = props.input
  return (
    <StyledSelectField {...StyledProps} meta={meta} hasValue={!!input.value}>
      <label htmlFor={input.name}>{label}</label>
      {placeholder && <div className="placeholder">{placeholder}</div>}
      <Select
        name={input.name}
        value={input.value.value}
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        options={options}
        {...props}
      />
      <StyledMessages>
        {meta.touched &&
          ((meta.error && <span className="error">{meta.error}</span>) ||
            (meta.warning && <span className="warning">{meta.warning}</span>))}
      </StyledMessages>
    </StyledSelectField>
  )
}

class TestingCycleForm extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { preMonitoring, handleChange, handleSubmit } = this.props
    return (<div>
      <Field
        label="18%"
        name="patientPercentage"
        className="form-control"
        component={SelectField}
        options={Config.get('/PATIENT_PERCENTAGE')}
      />
    </div>)
  }
}
```

All things are working but my input field gets cleared on focus out what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance... Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say “focus out” - does that mean it clears on blur? If so, does setting onBlurResetsInput and onCloseResetsInput to false help?

Update: here's the link to the [props table from the github readme](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#select-props). You've got to set both onBlurResetsInput and onCloseResetsInput to false at the same time, onBlurResetsInput set to false, by itself, will do nothing.

And also you need to remove the `onBlur` prop from the select which causes field clear on Blur

```
  <Select
    name={input.name}
    value={input.value.value}
    onChange={onChange}
    onBlurResetsInput={false}
    onCloseResetsInput={false}
    onFocus={onFocus}
    options={options}
    {...props}
  />
```

Comment: @Ashish You've got to do both at the same time. onBlurResetsInput does nothing when set to false unless onCloseResetsInput is also set to false.